# How to create a backup of a single OneNote notebook on a network drive that will also sync?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I have a OneNote notebook in my local Document folder. My employer does not use OneDrive or Sharepoint. I need to keep a copy of this OneNote on a network drive for backup purpose. I will usually use the local copy. The local copy must synchronize with the one on the network automatically when I get connected to network.

I only want to keep this one OneNote notebook in that network which has been assigned to me by the employer and don't want that all the OneNote notebooks I can open in OneNote get backup-ed into that location since that will take a very long time.

How to do this backup with automatic synchronize in OneNote?

Answer (score 0):

OneNote syncs locally by default if you open a notebook on a network drive.

So, place the Notebook on a network share, and then open it.

OneNote will save a copy of the notebook (and it's Recycle Bin/History) locally, and sync changes asynchronously back up to the network location. So being offline or disconnected from the network is no issue at all. OneNote handles this by default without any special config.

If the network location is entirely lost, you can find a full copy of the Notebook in your local profile folder to recover/recreate another network share with.

In other words, there's nothing to do but put the Notebook on your preferred network location and open it from there.

Comment: I pointed out the option to manually copy it in my answer.